# Make a path from a cut out path in Sketch

Tags: path, sketch-app

I have a sketch file with an icon where the icon shape is cut out from the surrounding box. I want to make this cut out bit into a real path so I can fill it with a color, but am unable to do so. I've been dabbling around with the boolean operation tools - but have not managed to succeed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to drag the Path out of the Object (aka Combined Shape) in the Layers List. Then you can color it independently. Make sure to place it below the Combined Shape to not cover it up.